# RabbitMQ File Size-based Log Rotation Default Size

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm new to RabbitMQ and I have an application that uses RabbitMQ as the message broker. Up until this day, I've been using the default settings - no log rotation. I wanted to use the log rotation feature so I set it using:

```
{log, [
        {file, [{file, "MyAppLogs.log"},
                {level, info},        
                {date, "$D0"},         
                {size, 1073741824},    
                {count, 30}            
                ]}
    ]}
```

Of course testing would take a while if I am to test 1GB file size, so for testing purposes I changed it to 1024 instead. I expected the log will rotate when it reaches 1KB but it did not. I've noticed that the log files would only rotate once the file size reaches 5KB. 
So my question is - is the minimum log file size for RabbitMQ file-based log rotation 5KB? 
I've looked around the web - especially in the rabbitmq documentation site: https://www.rabbitmq.com/logging.html - however there's no mention of any minimimum size. 
Here is the sample output of my the settings that I've used:
**Test Settings:**

```
[{file, [{file, "rabbit.log"},
              {level, info},
              {date, "$D0"},
              {size, 1024},
              {count, 3}
             ]}
     ]}
```

[image]

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/rabbitmq-users/wJGMVGB1cAk/discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log rotation is not necessarily precise due to when it happens in the logging process, as well as buffering.

Comment: I've answered in the rabbitmq-users mailing list - but for the sake of other readers in this question, I'm using Windows Server 2016, and RabbitMQ 3.8.2. I'm convinced it could be the logging process plus the buffering causing this. Setting the log file size to about 1MB produced more predictable results. I'll just mark your answer as the answer to my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This requires rabbitmq version > 3.7. Put the log rotate logics inside your `rabbitmq.conf` file like below:

```py
{log, [
        {file, [{file, "/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.log"}, %% log.file
                {level, info},        %% log.file.info
                {date, "$D0"},           %% log.file.rotation.date
                {size, 1024},            %% log.file.rotation.size
                {count, 15}            %% log.file.rotation.count
                ]}
    ]},
```

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is not clear - but yes, I put the logics in the rabbitmq.conf file. However, even when I set the log file size to just 1KB, it will not rotate - it does rotate at 5KB. So my question is, is this an implied minimum log file size?

Comment: What version of `RabbitMQ` are you on? This shouldn't happen. Their documentation doesn't say anything about 5kb limit.

Comment: I'm using RMQ 3.8.2.

Comment: I have added a screenshot showing the created log files during rotation. The file size is not consistent with the 1KB setting. I was expecting all rotated files will at least be the somewhere around 1KB.

Comment: Well, I investigated this on my machine. The issue is reproducible. In my case, I'm also seeing inconsistent log rotation. Although in my case, the filesize never goes over 2kb. File an issue in github maybe?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/rabbitmq-users/wJGMVGB1cAk/discussion